# How to set depth in Django serializer to relations depth?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I need to show all content of every related field on the way. If I try to set `depth = sys.maxint` it receives an error:

`AssertionError: 'depth' may not be greater than 10.`

Serializer exapmle:

```
class AppleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Apple
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = sys.maxint
```

So no values greater then 10. I have relation threads of more than 10 models so need some bigger depth. What is the way to set it bigger or just tell serializer to substitute content in all related fields trough all thread?

**EDITED**

The best practice I riched is to just make special serializers with expanding related fields in each of them so that'd look like this:

```
class OneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = One
        fields = '__all__'

class TwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    one = OneSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Two
        fields = '__all__'

class ThreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    two = TwoSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Three
        fields = '__all__'
```

But it requires to do all this middleware serializers so if I need only one the last in this serializers chain which has like 20 related models one by one I'd be required to create 20 not necessary serializers.

Comment: I believe if you define the related field/serialiser yourself you can ignore the depth attribute. Can you share your serializers?

Comment: @Iain i have simple serializers with only `class Meta` which only contains fields `model` and `fields = '__all__'`. I know i can reassign their fields and make them nested but i'm not sure that's best way for me to do that. Actually i also need to control this serializers and choice through request if i want to expand all records or i want to show only ids.